# Image as value of picklist

Tags: visualforce, picklist

I have a requirement where we need to show image as value of picklist. Is it possible in Salesforce ? (either via standard picklist functionality or apex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to use some Javascript plugins to achieve that "on select". If "after submitting the form" is acceptable - a simple formula field should do the trick as shown in Gaurav's answer.

Quick Googling:

- http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick
- http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/index.html

I've just tried with a really simple page that uses standard `select` and `option` tags (not the `apex:selectOption` etc) but the image is not shown (Chrome strips out the tag from the HTML, Firefox shows it in the source but marks as "stray tag <img>").

If that wouldn't be the case you could make do with pure HTML + some Javascript to sync the value to hidden field on each change...

```
<select id="workaround">
    <option value="0">Zero <img src="http://na1.salesforce.com/img/samples/stars_000.gif" /></option>
    <option value="1">One <img src="http://na1.salesforce.com/img/samples/stars_100.gif" /></option>
    <option value="2">Two <img src="http://na1.salesforce.com/img/samples/stars_200.gif" /></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

Salesforce doesn't support the facility to have an image as a value for a picklist. This has been discussed [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000glzzAAA) as well. However, you can employ a workaround such as using formula fields to pick an image based on the chosen picklist value.

For example

```
IF(
ISPICKVAL(Priority, "High"), IMAGE("/img/samples/flag_red.gif","high",30,30),null)
```